# FlexBuilder: Can it refactor at the package level? Am I doing something wrong?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, flexbuilder

I know that FlexBuiler's refactoring engine can deal with updating variable names… But I can't figure out if it's possible to refactor at the package level.

For example, I want to move `foo/a.as` to `foo/bar/a.as`, and I want the `package` path to be updated (ie, from `package foo` to `package foo.bar`) and references to be updated accordingly.

Does FlexBuilder support this sort of refactoring? Or am I just doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it does not.  Sorry.  Your only option is to follow that with Ctrl-H, and swap out foo. with foo.bar.

Answer (score 1):

The upcoming [Flash Builder 4](http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/flashbuilder4/) will support Move refactoring to move a class into a different package. A public beta is available on Adobe Labs.